# Scala upper and lower type bound

Tags: scala, generics

I'm having trouble finding a way in scala to simultaneously impose an upper and lower type bound. I need to make a generic function where the type parameter is both hashable (subtype of AnyRef) and nullable (supertype of Null).

I could achieve the former like this:

```
def foo[T <: AnyRef](t: T) = ???
```

And the latter like this:

```
def bar[T >: Null)(t: T) = ???
```

Is there a way that I can do both simultaneously? Thanks.

Comment: in general, i don't know whether it is possible to have type bounds in both directions. but in the specific case, aren't all subtypes of AnyRef  supertypes of Null in Scala?

Comment: No, because Nothing is a subtype of Null, and as such, it won't let me assign null to a variable of a type bounded by being a subtype of AnyRef.

Comment: huh. interesting. @lambdista's solution seems to work for me (while what i had tried, inverting the order of type bounds `def foo[T <: AnyRef >: Null]( t : T ) = ???` does not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
def foo[T >: Null <: AnyRef](t: T) = ???
```

It should work. That is:

```
foo(42) // does not compile 
foo(null) // compiles
foo("hello") // compiles
```

Answer (score 1):

Any type that is a subclass of `AnyRef` can be assigned the value `null`, so you do not need the upper bound.

```
def foo[T <: AnyRef](x: T) = x
foo(null) // returns null
```

That said, since you need to be able to hash the value, it should be noted that if you attempt to dereference `null` (e.g. `null.hashCode`) you will get a `NullPointerException`. For example:

```
def foo[T <: AnyRef](x: T) = x.hashCode
foo(null) // Throws an NPE
```

Furthermore, any use of `null` in *Scala* programs is strongly discouraged. Bearing all that in mind, I think what you might really want is something like this, which works for any type:

```
def foo[T](x: Option[T]) = x.hashCode
def foo(None) // Works. None is equivalent to no value (and Option(null) == None).
def foo(Some(1)) // Works. Note an Int isn't an AnyRef or nullable!
def foo(Some("Hello, world!")) // Works
def foo(Option(null)) // Works.
def foo(Option(z)) // Works, where z can be any reference type value, including null.
```

`Option[T]` is a functional means of dealing with undefined values (such as *nullable types*), and it works for any type `T`.