# How do I accept a generic that extends a class in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have something like the following...

```
class Base {
  def doSomething = {...}
}

class B extends Base{
  val text = "foo"
  ...
}
class C extends Base{
  val value = "bar"
}
```

I would like a method that accepts any class that extends Base but keeps its extended properties. I tried this...

```
def myMethod[A extends Base](obj: A): Unit{
  ...
}
```

But this didn't work. How do I create a method that allows this?

Comment: `[A <: Base]` extra characters so I can comment.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Don't answer the question in comments, answer in an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: It wasn't really a type because I was using Java syntax instead of Scala I would say this does constitute and answer

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed. It was due to a syntax misunderstanding, not a typo. Java developers just learning Scala are likely to be helped by this question and Luis's answer.

Comment: @Dylan No Stackoverflow is not a forum you ask any questions. It's a QnA collection and as you see from the closure comment, it needs to be reproducible issue.

Comment: @SwiftMango you're right, this isn't a forum, but OP's question fits the Q&A format perfectly (it clearly states the question and has a clear answer). Just because the question was answered in a comment doesn't mean it is no longer reproducible. I disagree with both reasons behind the closure vote, so I voted to reopen.

Comment: I agree with Dylan. This isn't a _hard_ question, but it is expressed very clearly and has a definitive answer. Responding by saying "read the docs" isn't helpful or welcoming for someone that clearly spent time trying to pose the question. The OP shouldn't be penalized because they didn't know what terminology to search for in the docs. I've gone through many badly formed questions in the review queues, and this is not one.

Comment: I did consider dupe-hammering it with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46633643/scala-upper-and-lower-type-bound). But people will keep googling for `extends`, nothing one can do about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept that you are looking for is that of an *upper type bound*. The [standard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) for the subtyping relation is `<:`. This exact notation is also used in the Scala syntax for expressing type bounds:

```
// upper type bound, `A` must be subtype of `U`,
// analogous to Java's "A extends U"
def foo[A <: U]: Unit = ???

// lower type bound, `A` must be supertype of `L`,
// analogous to Java's "A super L"
def bar[A >: L]: Unit = ???

// Both upper and lower bounds simultaneously:
def baz[A >: U <: L]: Unit = ???
```

In your case, `A` should be subtype of `Base`, i.e. it should be bounded by `Base` from above: `A <: Base`

```
def myMethod[A <: Base](obj: A): Unit{
  ...
}
```

Another important difference to keep in mind when coming from Java is that in Scala, you have both the possibility for use-site variance, as well as declaration-site variance.